# Burninate the [rant] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [rant](/questions/tagged/rant) tag currently has 17 questions.

But we do not accept (nor welcome) "rants" here, and authors admitting their question is a rant by using this tag should technically/arguably have their question closed as "not seeking input from the community".

Should we douse it in petrol and nonchalantly toss a Zippo at it?

---

EDIT to respond to Catija's comment:

> Have you actually read the full tag wiki? It seems to pretty clearly
>   explain when it's acceptable to use the tag and what sorts of rants
>   are OK.

In one sense, this is very much a valid argument. And the tag is arguably safe and setup to be used in a specific way.

However, a "rant" is *commonly* or *generally* taken as someone "moaning" about something in (usually) a non-productive, unmeaningful, non-constructive way.

I don't see the point of having a tag of a word which is generally taken as a negative attitude, and using the tag's wiki to explain why it should not be used in the negative way that generally is.
The fact the tag wiki is so comprehensive kinda proves the potential problem exists.

Some of the "rant" questions are ok, and arguably as there are only 17 questions over 5 years there is no major issue.
But I don't think it needs to exist, and better to get rid now than when it becomes more noticed because it's being used on more questions.

What possible use or purpose could this tag have which we cannot manage without it?
The questions which seem ok could survive perfectly well with just the "discussion" or "feature-request" tags, and potentially some better tags to hone in the topic they are discussing.

Comment: Have you actually read the full tag wiki? It seems to pretty clearly explain when it's acceptable to use the tag and what sorts of rants are OK.

Comment: @Catija Yes, please see my edit :)

Comment: The only reason I can imagine the tag can be useful is for posts where we want to discuss posts or behavior of users that are rants. But that is not reflected in the tag wiki which makes my point rather useless.

Comment: @rene For discussion posts, we have [meta-tag:specific-question] (and "specific answers", "specific edit", tags etc). We tend to stray away from discussing "specific users", and if something does need discussing it's more likely the "problem" or a site specific thing we'd be discussing, which we likely have a tag for already. The "rant" tag wouldn't add value even if we were discussing a user who ranted. The title and question would cater for that "Was this user's behaviour bad" or "Are rants like this allowed" etc.

Comment: I feel I'm not going to win this argument but I'll refrain from a rant ... this time... ;)

Comment: @rene :) Ironically, I love a good rant...